# How to create an instance of CriteriaBuilder using JPA

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, hibernate-criteria

How to create an instance of CriteriaBuilder using JPA in a provider agnostic way? i.e. we **don't** want to use HibernateUtil to fetch HibernateSession

```
Session session = HibernateUtil.getHibernateSession();
CriteriaBuilder cb = session.getCriteriaBuilder();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A provider agnostic way to create instance of CriteriaBuilder in Spring Boot JPA:

```
import jakarta.persistence.EntityManager;

@Autowired
private EntityManager entityManager;
// ...

CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
```